# How to deploy my website with one click using Git Bash on windows and a scripted command

Tags: bash, git, deployment, oneclick, one-click-web-publishing

I have a html/css/js website which is stored in GitHub and developed on my Windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2019.

Currently I'm deploying it using the Git Bash console and then running a git ftp command to push any deltas to the server.

Specifically:

1. I have pinned shortcut on the task bar which opens Git Bash in the root directory of the website.  [image]
2. Once the console has opened, I execute the following command to push to the server: "git ftp -v -u "frankray" push"

A two click deployment is no big deal, but I'd really like to do this in one click from the task bar (as a prelude to automating the CI).

**Problem:** I cannot for the life of me workout how to pass in the git ftp command into the console and run it, say from a batch file or perhaps directly calling git-bash.exe with the command passed in as a parameter.

I can't imagine it's hard to do, but I haven't worked out what I've been doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Maybe [this post from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1104567/how-can-i-find-out-the-command-line-options-for-git-bash-exe) could help! Try something like the following 'target': `"C:\Program Filies\Git\git-bash.exe" -c 'git ftp -v -u "frankray" push'`

Comment: @0stone0 Thanks, that superuser link points ultimately to the solution, "Correct there isn't a list of command line options help for git-bash.exe". Also your suggestion above works (except type-o 'Filies' in your path).  if you want to repost it as the question answer, I'd be happy to mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Posting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726892/how-to-deploy-my-website-with-one-click-using-git-bash-on-windows-and-a-scripted/63740971#comment112690416_63726892) as an answer</sub>

Unfortunately there isn't a list of command line options for git-bash. This [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1104567/how-can-i-find-out-the-command-line-options-for-git-bash-exe) question may provide some more info.

---

A possible solution ([verified by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726892/how-to-deploy-my-website-with-one-click-using-git-bash-on-windows-and-a-scripted/63740971#comment112709110_63726892)) is passing the `-c` parameter (command to be executed) to the *target* like so;

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd="C:\Users\frank\Documents\Professional\Contracting\5. Frank Ray & Associates Ltd\Website\frankray.net" -c 'git ftp -v -u "frankray" push ; read -p "Press any key to continue"'
```